# Ambiguous invocation match confusion

Tags: c#, null, nullable, overload-resolution

The following code throws "Ambiguous invocation match" at compile time:

```
class ABC{}
class DEF{}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(func(null));
    }
    static string func(ABC abc)
    {
        return "";
    }
    static string func(DEF def)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

But the following code compiles and runs fine:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(func(null));
}
static string func(int? abc)
{
    return "function a";
}
static string func(float? def)
{
    return "function b";
}
```

Outputting

```
function a
```

How does C# know what which function to pick in the second example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the compiler performs overload resolution on a function call like this it chooses the *better function member* among the candidates, if one exists. The definition of *better function member* includes this passage in §7.5.3.2 of the C# language spec:

> 7.5.3.2 Better function member
>
> [...]
>
> Given an argument list A with a set of argument expressions { E1, E2,
>   ..., EN } and two applicable function members MP and MQ with parameter
>   types { P1, P2, ..., PN } and { Q1, Q2, ..., QN }, MP is defined to be
>   a better function member than MQ if
>
> - for each argument, the implicit conversion from EX to QX is
>     not better than the implicit conversion from EX to PX, and
> - for at least one argument, the conversion from EX to PX is
>     better than the conversion from EX to QX.
>
> [...]

In this case, `MP` is the first method (`P1` being `int?`) and `MQ` is the second method (`Q1` being `float?`). So the behavior is easily explained if we can prove that the conversion from `null` to `int?` is *better* than the conversion to `float?`.

This is determined by the rules in §7.5.3.5:

> 7.5.3.5 Better conversion target
>
> Given two different types T1 and T2, T1 is a better conversion target
>   than T2 if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - An implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists, and no implicit conversion from T2 to T1 exists

Since an implicit conversion from `int` to `float` exists but one from `float` to `int` does not ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx)), `int` is the *better conversion target* when choosing between the two types.

In your example we are dealing with the nullable versions of these types, but the same logic applies because of

> 6.1.4 Implicit nullable conversions
>
> Predefined implicit conversions that operate on non-nullable value
>   types can also be used with nullable forms of those types.

Comment: `
float f = 1;//works
int i = 1.0f;//doesnt work
`

Ok that makes sense